# Can't turn on WIFI on Lenovo z580 using Fn+F5

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I can't turn my wireless adapter on using the network settings it says wireless is disabled by wireless switch. On my computer the hardware switch is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. When I press it nothing happens. Anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

I found out my hard ware witch although it doesn’t do any thing works fine. when I do

```
# rfkill list
```

I get

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

then I pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> and did

```
# rfkill list
```

And got the below result

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

that proves that the key combination works. I checked my BIOS too wlan is enabled.

And `# sudo lshw -class network`
gave me

```
 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 04:7d:7b:f2:b6:4d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.0.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0404000-f0404fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 74:e5:43:0f:2f:47
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.5.0-25-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:18 memory:f0500000-f050ffff
```

command :`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

result :

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3975]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:31a1]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

command: `lsmod`

result :

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ipheth                 13449  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32049  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    78147  1 
parport_pc             32689  0 
ppdev                  17074  0 
bnep                   18141  2 
rfcomm                 46620  0 
coretemp               13401  0 
kvm                   414071  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13221  0 
aesni_intel            51038  0 
cryptd                 20404  2 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
aes_x86_64             17256  1 aesni_intel
microcode              22804  0 
ideapad_laptop         18087  0 
sparse_keymap          13891  1 ideapad_laptop
arc4                   12530  2 
snd_hda_intel          33492  3 
snd_hda_codec         134213  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              17699  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                96668  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13325  0 
snd_rawmidi            30513  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14900  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61555  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29426  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14498  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
wmi                    19071  0 
joydev                 17458  0 
mac_hid                13206  0 
snd                    78921  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
ath9k                 131355  0 
mac80211              540032  1 ath9k
psmouse                95595  0 
serio_raw              13216  0 
ath9k_common           14056  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              395307  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    23828  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
rts5139               356200  0 
uvcvideo               76750  0 
videobuf2_core         32852  1 uvcvideo
videodev              120310  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12861  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13405  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
i915                  520615  3 
ath3k                  12919  0 
btusb                  22475  0 
bluetooth             209249  13 bnep,rfcomm,ath3k,btusb
drm_kms_helper         49113  1 i915
drm                   288721  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13414  1 i915
mei                    40691  0 
cfg80211              206797  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
video                  19391  1 i915
lpc_ich                17062  0 
soundcore              15048  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18485  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lp                     17760  0 
parport                46346  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
hid_generic            12541  0 
usbhid                 46987  0 
hid                   100411  2 hid_generic,usbhid
r8169                  61651  0
```

command : `lsb_release -rcd`

result :

```
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal
```

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into then edit your question and include here any useful info.

Comment: Probably we will need more info. Include the results of the following commands  `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and `lsmod` and `lsb_release -rcd`

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `hard ware witch` to `hardware which` so that online language translators can work properly.

Answer (score 1):

first, you can check in the system settings if the key combinations Fn + F5 is correctly assign. depending on your computer specs, some key combinations may be not assigned.

you can go in the system settings, keyboard (in hardware section), shortcuts, and assign it from there (if needed).

other way, you can install xdotool

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

and config it from there.

xbindkeys is a third alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands

```
sudo modprobe -rvf ideapad-laptop
sudo modprobe -rvf ath3k 
sudo modprobe -rvf ath9k
```

Then

```
sudo modprobe ath9k
```

Wait for 10 secs and..

...Check again the results of `rfkill list all`  before and after the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

See if your wireless is up and running now. 
It seems to me like a mess up with ideapad-laptop module , see `modinfo ideapad-laptop` from more.

Also for some reason , 2 modules of atheros are loaded. `ath3k` and `ath9k`. You need only the `ath9k`.

Above commands will unload the modules and re-load only the `ath9k`.

If this works , maybe you need to unload the module every time you boot your PC. 
An entry in `/etc/rc.local` maybe help.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work 

`3: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
4: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
` after pressing key combination

Comment: Try to set in BIOS configuration page , the NET device as first on boot order.

Comment: what returns 
"modinfo ath9k" ? may be you have to disable hardware encryption, like explained here : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1781350&page=2

Comment: through trial and error I got
`0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
` now i dot get a wireless option in my network settings

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on Lenovo B570 by reseting the BIOS (after several tries).
Turn on the computer, get into the BIOS with <kbd>F2</kbd> key and reset it with <kbd>F9</kbd> key.

Hope it helps!